# click() not working occassionally in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I had written a script in selenium webdriver which uses `click()` to click on a button which is a "dojo" element.

Previously it was working fine but its not working now, i have tried all the possible ways to make it work (using javascipt, waiting for element to be present, checking enabled and disabled options etc etc) but nothing seems to work.

I would really appreciate if anybody could help me out with this. thanks in advance. i am attaching the script and html code for ur reference.

```
public void Search_Project_Test(String Project_name,String Os_type,String Start_rel,String End_rel) throws InterruptedException, IOException
     {
        this.Software_type.click();

        this.select_os_type(Os_type);

        this.search_proj.sendKeys(Project_name);
        com.wait_till_pageload();
        SORA_Constants.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='submit_project_search']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: Define "not working"  Is there an exception?  Is nothing happening?  It would also be helpful to see the HTML of the element you are trying to interact with.

Comment: nothing is happening at all, not even an exception is being thrown. here is the html code "<button id="submit_project_search" class="dijitReset dijitStretch xwt-TextButtonContents" waistate="labelledby-submit_project_search_label" wairole="button" value="Search Project" type="submit" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-labelledby="submit_project_search_label" style="-moz-user-select: none;">"

Comment: What version of FF and Selenium are you using?

Comment: i m using firefox 31.0 and selenium 2.42.2

Comment: @NilamberSingh , I am not sure but seems like selenium version 2.41 only supports up to Firefox 28, and no mention of firefox 31 is made in selenium 2.42.2. I would recommend downgrading firefox to 28.

Comment: thanx @Amey i downgraded the version to 26 and bang the problem is solved. thanx again for ur suggestion. Appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ! And also check that element is visible on the page

```
SORA_Constants.driver.findElement(By.id("submit_project_search")).click();
```

Comment: as mentioned, i have tried each and every thing. problem is not with identifying the element, problem is with the click() which is neither clicking nor giving any exception like element not found or element not visible.

Comment: SORA_Constants.driver.findElement(By.id("submit_project_search")).submit();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SORA_Constants.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='submit_project_search']")).SendKeys("\n");
```

or:

```
SORA_Constants.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='submit_project_search']")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Answer (score 0):

IT worked finally, all I did is upgraded the FireFox version. i was using 23.0 and later switched to 26.0 which resolved the problem. i never knew if selenium had such kind of issues with different versions of firefox. Hope if anyone faces similiar kind of situation later, then this could b helpful. :)